# Spark SQL Query Plans

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark and I am trying to understand sql query plans.

What do the numbers in parentheses at the beginning of a line signify ?

Eg consider the following query plan:

```
= Physical Plan ==
*(7) HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[sum(id#36L)])
+- Exchange SinglePartition
   +- *(6) HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[partial_sum(id#36L)])
      +- *(6) Project [id#36L]
         +- *(6) SortMergeJoin [id#36L], [id#32L], Inner
            :- *(3) Sort [id#36L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
            :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#36L, 200)
            :     +- *(2) Project [(id#30L * 5) AS id#36L]
            :        +- Exchange RoundRobinPartitioning(7)
            :           +- *(1) Range (1, 10000000, step=1, splits=6)
            +- *(5) Sort [id#32L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
               +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#32L, 200)
                  +- Exchange RoundRobinPartitioning(9)
                     +- *(4) Range (1, 10000000, step=2, splits=6)
```

What do the numbers at the beginning of the lines mean ? For e.g. *(2) or *(5) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The number that you see at the beginning of the lines are for the wholestage codegen stages. Everything with the same index number is in one stage. So, stage boundaries can be recognized by exchange operations that involve a shuffle.

Just to get the gist out of it see the statement below:

`WholeStageCodegenExec` marks the child physical operator with * (star) prefix and per-query codegen stage ID (in round brackets) in the text representation of a physical plan tree.

You can find the detail information here :
https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/content/spark-sql-SparkPlan-WholeStageCodegenExec.html#codegenStageId